# Is it usual to use transform skew instead of font-style italic

Tags: css, fonts, transform, pagespeed, typography

**Page speed optimilization**

I only have couple 1-line sentences (h1, h2) in italic and I don't know what is smarter:

- set font-style italic (import italic font - 100-200kb extra)
- simply use transform: skew(-15deg);

---

**WHY?!** I just don't know if this is a normal solution and usual to do. I know it is really stupid to use this solution on paragraphs and that's NOT my question here.

Comment: not all fonts will look good skewed. italicizing isn't just a matter of "leaning" a character.

Comment: You can't just use an `<em>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid Browser Compatibility issue and to avoid hassle of handling for different browsers, I strongly suggest you to go with old classic `italic` unless it fulfill your requirement.